# How to make the gradient come on top of image and behind the text?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

i have been trying to place the grandient on top of the image and behind the text but everything i tried from what i could find out in web didnt worked.
i would need to have the source of the image in the div cause if its in the css code it will apply the same image to all other templates i create.

thanks :)

```
<div class="titles">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img overlay" 
         height=260px 
         width=240px 
         alt="Shokugeki no Souma: Ni no Sara" 
         src="https://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/184719.jpg" />
            <div class="titulo">Shokugeki no Souma: Ni no Sara</div>
            <div class="epis">Epis. 12</div>
    </div>
```

```
.titles .thumb {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 260px;
    width: 245px;
    max-height: 260px;
    max-width: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
 }

 .thumb .titulo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.thumb .epis {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.titles .thumb .img:hover {
    max-height: 260px;
    max-width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    width: 240px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.img.overlay {
  background: linear-gradient( 
    to bottom,   
      black, 
      rgba(64,64,64,1),
      rgba(64,64,64,1),
      rgba(64,64,64,1),
      rgba(64,64,64,1),
      rgba(64,64,64,1),
      rgba(64,64,64,1), 
      black);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind explaining a bit more about what is going wrong when you try to implement this?

My suggestion would be to put the overlay in its own separate div instead of inside the image tag.  Then close the overlay div before you start your caption div.  Then you can set your "thumb" class to have a certain width and height in your css, and style the overlay div to have height:100% width:100%so that it completely covers your thumbnail image.  If you absolutely position the caption text, you can place it on top of the gradient.   For example

```
<div class="titles">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img alt="Shokugeki no Souma: Ni no Sara" src="https://img7.anidb.net/pics/anime/184719.jpg" />
     <div class="overlay"></div>      
            <div class="titulo">Shokugeki no Souma: Ni no Sara</div>
            <div class="epis">Epis. 12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, when i try to implement the gradient it always stays in the back of the image, i "tried" (just started coding with html+css like 2 weeks ago so i'm not really experienced with it yet, so i'm not sure if i did it correctly) the way you explained, also using z-index and changing absolute/relative positions but so far nothing, closest i could get was something like this: 
http://codepen.io/DrakonArc/pen/grVxGx

i added a letter to the url of the image so it would end up with a error in the url path and it becomes like that, the gradient is there behind the text.

Comment: I forked your Codepen here and implemented my above suggestion: http://codepen.io/bananahavana/full/pbrLzN/  Is this what youre trying to accomplish?

Comment: wanted to show you how it looked in the website but, it seems we cant message users.